# onchange of one select other select option should change and i should get the data in alert of submit

Tags: reactjs

Hi all I am unable to set the value of `value1` if I am changing the value from parent select. I am able to render different select on changing the options of parent select, but I am not able to set the value.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class FlavorForm extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = {value: 'HR',value1 : '1'};

      this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
      this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
      this.handleChange1 = this.handleChange1.bind(this);
    }

    handleChange(event) {
      this.setState({value: event.target.value});
    }

    handleSubmit(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      alert(this.state.value , this.state.value1);
    }
    getsecondselect = () => {
        if(this.state.value === "HR"){
            //gethrcontent = () => {
                return (
                    <label>
                        Pick your HR:
                        <select value1={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChange1}>
                        <option value="1">1</option>
                        <option value="2">2</option>
                        <option value="3">3</option>
                        <option value="4">4</option>
                        </select>
                    </label>
                )//};
        }
        else{
        //getslectedenrollment = () => {
            return (
                <label>
                    Pick your Enrollment:
                    <select value1={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChange1}>
                    <option value="5">5</option>
                    <option value="6">6</option>
                    <option value="7">7</option>
                    <option value="8">8</option>
                    </select>
                </label>
          )//};
        }
        }
        handleChange1(event) {
            this.setState({value1: event.target.value1});
            alert(this.state.value1);
          }
    render() {

      return (
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
          <label>
            Pick your favorite flavor:
            <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
              <option value="HR">HR</option>
              <option value="enrollment">enrollment</option>
            </select>
          </label>
          {getsecondselect()}
          <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
      );
    }
  }


export default FlavorForm;
```

Comment: Can you help explain the difference between `value` and `value1`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some changes to the code, but as stackoverfloweth mentioned, you had `event.target.value1` instead of `event.target.value`.

Also, you need `this.getsecondselect()` in the render function of the code you posted.

Working CodeSandbox [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/1z8w9wzj9l).

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";

class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    value: "HR",
    number: "1"
  };

  handleChangeValue = event => {
    this.setState({ value: event.target.value });
  };

  handleSubmit = event => {
    event.preventDefault();
    alert(`${this.state.value} --> ${this.state.number}`);
  };

  getSecondSelect = () => {
    if (this.state.value === "HR") {
      return (
        <label>
          Pick your HR:
          <select value1={this.state.number} onChange={this.handleChangeNumber}>
            <option value="1">1</option>
            <option value="2">2</option>
            <option value="3">3</option>
            <option value="4">4</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      ); //};
    } else {
      //getslectedenrollment = () => {
      return (
        <label>
          Pick your Enrollment:
          <select value1={this.state.value1} onChange={this.handleChangeNumber}>
            <option value="5">5</option>
            <option value="6">6</option>
            <option value="7">7</option>
            <option value="8">8</option>
          </select>
        </label>
      ); //};
    }
  };

  handleChangeNumber = event => {
    this.setState({ number: event.target.value });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>
          Pick your favorite flavor:
          <select value={this.state.value} onChange={this.handleChangeValue}>
            <option value="HR">HR</option>
            <option value="enrollment">enrollment</option>
          </select>
        </label>
        {this.getSecondSelect()}
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    );
  }
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like both of your selects are setup to have `value={this.state.value1}` and onchange they both call `this.handleChange1`. Not sure if that's an issue.

I also noticed that within `handleChange1` you are updating the state with a prop `event.target.value1` but the options do not have `value1` defined.. perhaps you meant to use `event.target.value`?

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for the help. this.handlechange1 is not an issue as i tried other function also. but your other suggestion worked.
but still when i am trying to change the data and putting alert it is showing previous one which i last changed. i mean i wrote the alert after changing the state. so it should give an output with the new changed data right.